MIN() not funciona, no entrega el minimo
Necesito obtener el mínimo de la temperatura solo el día de hoy, columna temp.
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "
  SELECT MAX(temp)
  FROM z_basexp
  WHERE fecha 
    BETWEEN
        CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00')
    AND CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 23:59:59')
");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
echo $row[0];

Me devuelve 9.99°C, ¿porque? si en el id = 31 esta la mínima temperatura, el formato de las variable temp es varchar. Ayuda please

Hola, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías compartir algunos datos de la tabla? Dices que en la fila con id 31 hay una temperatura mínima, pero nosotros no podemos verlo. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir más información. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio).

También, dices que quieres la temperatura mínima con min() pero en el código compartido estás usando max(), lo que explicaría por qué te está devolviendo un número (en modo varchar) empezado en 9.

En la consulta tienes MAX() en vez de un MIN(). Pero bueno, parece que tu problema es porque tienes ese campo numérico como VARCHAR. Lo que hace SQL es simplemente un ordenamiento alfabético y de devuelve el valor máximo o mínimo según la lógica alfanumérica. Por ejemplo: '80' será mayor que '110' porque '8' > '1'. Se pueden hacer conversiones, pero recomiendo esa columna mejor la cambies a DECIMAL

Dado que almacenas la unidad de medida como parte de la cadena, no va a haber función estándar que pueda ayudarte, pues no hay función estándar que sea capaz de comparar las cadenas '9.99°C', '17.14°F', '321.14°K'. Si aún puedes, cambia el diseño, almacena un número, en una unidad de medida definida por el sistema, y ya en la capa de presentación capturas y muestras al usuario las temperaturas en función de su preferencia. Al tener todo en la unidad que elijas, y tener almacenado un número, entonces si que la función min() puede ayudarte.

Es un grave error de diseño guardar datos formateados. Encontrarás problemas como el actual, en que será difícil ordenar los datos. Otros problemas adicionales serán: hacer comparaciones; hacer cálculos como promedios de temperaturas; hacer conversiones de Celsius a Fahrenheit, Kelvin, Rankine...; mayor posibilidad de errores al introducir los datos, etc. Es mejor declarar un tipo de datos apropiado, por ejemplo DECIMAL y presentar lo relativo al formato en la salida.

El problema esta en el tipo de dato, debe ser decimal y no varchar.

Alvaro, muchas gracias fue un problema de conversion de varchar -> decimal, soy nuevo sorry, algo básico.
Dejo el código. saludos.
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "
  SELECT MAX(convert(temp), decimal(3,2))
  FROM z_basexp
  WHERE fecha
    BETWEEN
        CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00')
    AND CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 23:59:59')
");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
echo $row[0];


No solo la sintaxis es incorrecta, sino que convert() va a dar un error con una cadena como la que el AP dice que tiene almacenada: '9.99°C'.

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT MIN(CONVERT(temp, decimal(3,2))) 
    FROM z_basexp 
    WHERE fecha BETWEEN CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 23:59:59')");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];

el código correcto

Hola Jose, esto no debería funcionar.

Marcos tiene razón, y no funcionaría por lo mismo que he dicho en tu otra respuesta :/
